# How to return the function name?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I wrote a class and I want to return the names of function which I implemented inside the class.

```
public class cls
{
    public static string fun()
    {
      //code
    }
}
```

Simply I want to know how to know the name of the function (which is `fun`), not the return value of that function.

Comment: `Messages` is the name of the _class_. The function would be `Saved`. What do you want, exactly?

Comment: @Etienne de Martel, maybe next time you can do the appropriate edit.

Comment: @Etienne I didn't mean anything with saved

Comment: @Slomojo I did not even know what he wanted, exatly. How can I edit in these conditions?

Comment: @Etienne de Martel - Sorry, the question seemed pretty obvious, with a similarly obvious typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void TraceContext(string messageFormat)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format(messageFormat, 
        new System.Diagnostics.StackFrame(1).GetMethod().Name));
}
```

See [How To: Obtain Method Name Programmatically For Tracing](http://weblogs.asp.net/palermo4/archive/2007/07/08/how-to-obtain-method-name-programmatically-for-tracing.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use reflection, try http://www.csharp-examples.net/get-method-names/

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to do this

```
typeof(Messages).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
.Select(m=>m.Name)
.ToArray()
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work with the methods described above, because 'Saved' is static. You'd need to add '| BindingFlags.Static' to get that one.

Answer (score 1):

For the case in your question, this will work:

```
var methods = typeof (Messages).GetMethods(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
foreach(var method in methods)
{
    Console.WriteLine(method.Name);
}
```

If you need other data (for example, inherited methods from a parent class), you'll need other combinations of [BindingFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Um, what?
The **Class** name is Messages. The **Function** is named Saved. 
Either you've made a typo, or you've omitted something important from your code/description.

In any case, the functionality you're after is contained in the Reflection namespace.

No offense intended, but based on how you've worded your description, I'm going to assume no prior knowledge of reflection, in which case I recommend the following [introductory tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/C__Reflection_Tutorial.aspx)